# tf name conflict

Tags: ros-melodic, tf2-ros

I'm wandering the way to use two cameras with different tf name.
I use two relasense camera, one is one the ceiling (bird view), the other is on my robot (robot view).

Since launching the same file, their tf name conflicts. How can i modify thier name?
I wanna use bird view for detecting apriltags and robot view for mapping. That's why i need to distingish them...

Hope anyone has good idea!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

To differentiate the cameras with the [realsense-ros](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/tree/ros1-legacy) driver for ROS melodic you can set the `~tf_prefix` parameter in the launch file. From the readme:

`tf_prefix: By default all frame's ids have the same prefix - camera_. This allows changing it per camera.`

Setting this individually for each camera would look something like:

```xml
<!-- other args -->

<include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/includes/nodelet.launch.xml">
    <arg name="tf_prefix"                value="ceiling"/>
    <!-- other args -->
</include>

<include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/includes/nodelet.launch.xml">
    <arg name="tf_prefix"                value="robot"/>
    <!-- other args -->
</include>
```

This will give each camera its own TF frame that you can look up without conflict.